# DTDs constructed by HXT picklers

Tags: xml, haskell, dtd, hxt

I'm having trouble coaxing the package **hxt** into constructing a DTD which correctly represents defaulted XML-*attributes*.

The DTD contained in my *pickler*, erroneously requires an explicit value for *attributes* for which a default value has been defined. The *pickler* correctly applies the default value when parsing unvalidated input, but fails when validating the input against the DTD, which requires an explicit *attribute*-value.

As an example using **ghci**, I create a *pickler* for an *attribute* & define a default value, then extract the DTD, which specifies that a value is **REQUIRED**.
If one defines the default value TWICE, then oddly the DTD defines that the value is **IMPLIED**.
If one alternatively defines the value as a *element* rather than an *attribute*, then the DTD quantifies the value by '**?**', suggesting that it's optional; better, but I wanted an *attribute*.

```
Prelude> :m + Text.XML.HXT.Core
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> _ <- runX $ constA undefined >>> xpickleWriteDTD (xpElem "root" . xpDefault 0 $ xpAttr "attr" xpInt) [] "-" --There's probably an easier way of achieving this.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root EMPTY >
<!ATTLIST root attr CDATA #REQUIRED >
]>
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> _ <- runX $ constA undefined >>> xpickleWriteDTD (xpElem "root" . xpDefault 0 . xpAttr "attr" $ xpDefault undefined xpInt) [] "-"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root EMPTY >
<!ATTLIST root attr CDATA #IMPLIED >
]>
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> _ <- runX $ constA undefined >>> xpickleWriteDTD (xpElem "root" . xpDefault 0 $ xpElem "elem" xpInt) [] "-"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                                
<!DOCTYPE root [                                                                                                                                                                      
<!ELEMENT elem (#PCDATA) >                                                                                                                                                            
<!ELEMENT root (elem)? >                                                                                                                                                              
]>
```

Comment: I removed GHCi's `Loading package...` spam since it was cluttering up the post and since the version numbers of the packages are likely not that important. If they turn out to be, they are still available in the revision history and can be edited back in.

Answer (score 1):

I have received a response from the author of this package, which clarifies the issue;

> I suspect, with the current version of **HXT** it's not possible do describe default values for *attributes* within the *pickler* module. The feature of deriving a DTD out of the *picklers* is somewhat experimental and we have not implemented every corner case available in DTDs. In the datatype used in the *picklers* for schema info (DTD or other schemata) there's no field holding a default *attribute* value.